# how to make boto3 connect to default working folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

My s3 account is only woking at specific folder, like: 'A/B/C/'

When I using the following code, I still have the access deny issue:

```
from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.client('s3')
prefix = 'A/B/C/'

for x in s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=aws_bucket, Prefix=prefix):
    print(x)
```

I also tried startAfter, still failed to access denied:

```
from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.client('s3')
start_after = 'A/B/C/'

for x in s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=aws_bucket, StartAfter=start_after):
    print(x)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug5.py", line 39, in <module>
    for x in s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=aws_bucket, StartAfter=start_after):
  File "/Users/ken/PythonVM3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/ken/PythonVM3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Dose the Boto3 provide a feature, that we could connect to the default working folder: A/B/C?

Note:
I could use Cyberduck to access the certain folder: A/B/C
That means the AWS Config side is expected

Comment: Is there a policy on the bucket denying the access, or is it your IAM user's policy?

Comment: I could use Cyberduck to access the certain folder: A/B/C. That means the AWS Config side is expected

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have attached IAM policy with below permissions (S3 Full permission) to your IAM user. You can give  permissions as per your requirements.

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But I could use Cyberduck to access the certain folder: A/B/C. That means the IAM Config side is expected. Right?

Comment: not sure about Cyberduck but this is the very Basic permission set for S3 bucket. Try at-least once and let me know.

Comment: Just for your information, You only need `s3:ListBucket` permission for this  operation. check link : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2